# How to use @Scope("prototype") for service layer?

Tags: session, spring-mvc

I want to use `@Scope("prototype")` to have differents sessions because actually i have a probleme with session !! If first user use session, so another user can't find what he should find !

I don't know what can i do fo that ! So i have my applicationContexte, and my dao layer and all work fine but sessions no! And I use `spring mvc` as framework to implement mvc architecture.
Have you any suggestion please ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is not working with Sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Scope("session"). This scopes a bean definition to an HTTP session and is only valid in the context of ApplicationContext:

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
@SessionAttributes("theAttribute")
public class MyController {


     private MyClass theAttribute;

     ...
}
```

With this theAttribute depends on the session, and each user has a new instance of theAttribute